# Unable to edit ACF field on WooCommerce product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I have created an image field and assigned it to show up where Taxonomy Term is equal to product_cat on a standard installation of WooCommerce.

If I click on Products > Category, I **can** see the ACF field in the left column of the page (the form to add a new category) at this URL:

```
  /wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=product_cat&post_type=product
```

But if I click to edit any of the categories, I **cannot** see that ACF field, at this URL:

```
  /wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=product_cat&tag_ID=335&post_type=product
```

Things I've tried already:

- There are no javascript errors on the page
- No php errors that I can see when I turn on WP_Debug
- No changes when I enable the default theme
- No changes when I disable all plugins (except WooCommerce and ACF)

  This is driving me crazy, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where are you getting this link `/wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=product_cat&tag_ID=335&post_type=product'? For me its `edit-tags.php` for both adding and editing the tags.

Comment: @AmitJoshi On edit-tags.php, if I want to edit a specific term, I hover over a term and click 'Edit'. That link brings me to term.php and the ACF fields are missing on this page.

Comment: What wordpress version are you using?

Comment: Wordpress version is 4.8

Comment: what version is your acf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using ACF versions below 5.3.7, this is an issue.

Kindly update to the latest version which is 5.6.0 and you will not get this problem.

Comment: Thank you! I was expecting to see a notification that my version was out of date but there was no notification, so I assumed I was using the most up to date version of the plugin. 5.6 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to Woocommerce/ACF only adding in that Custom Field when you create a new category.

They might have simply *not included it in the edit category/term page template*.

Which means you probably need to add that image while creating the categories, you can always ask Woocommerce support directly if this feature can be added.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Wp version 4.8 and ACF version 5.5 and its working fine for me. the Tax Image field shows up when I add new category as well as when I edit those categories. See below for the settings I have. As long as you have similar rules, this should work. If not upgrade to the latest verison of ACF and try this.[image: ACG settings]